# Sticky header on scroll in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a page with ScrollView, which contains a fixed section and then a repeatable section. Every repeatable section contains a title. I want to stick this title when each item reaches to top.

This functionality is pretty easy to achieve in web. Below is the link which has the exact behavior that i want to implement in my NativeScript App.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ii5tnn

Comment: You will have to use [Parallax Scrolling](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b9hyJh&v=2). The first half of the screen will use Parallax, the second half can use a ScrollView.